# How to hide repeated date?

Tags: php, html

I have table like this?

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h80S3.jpg)

But I want this type of records in table like this

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF0ti.jpg)

**My Code:**

```
foreach ($record as $value) { ?> 

    <tr>
        <?php if($i - 1 == 1){ $i = 0; ?> 
            <td><?php echo $value['date']; ?></td> 
        <?php }else{ ?> 
            <td></td> 
        <?php } ?> 
        <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td> 
        <td><?php echo $value['mobile']; ?></td> 
    </tr> 

<?php $i++;} ?>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code you tried but didn't work?

Comment: foreach ($record as $value) {

 ?>
 <tr>
  <?php if($i - 1 == 1){ $i = 0; ?>
  <td><?php echo $value['date']; ?></td>
 <?php }else{ ?>
  <td></td>
 <?php } ?>
  <td><?php echo $value['name']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['email']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $value['mobile']; ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php $i++;} ?>

Comment: Not as a comment - as part of your question.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Can you please write both tables in your Question? Working with linked pictures is not very user-friendly for helpers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution & Explanation:**

I am setting $previous to always equal the previous loops date value.

If the date value of the current loop matches the previous one, then $date will equal nothing, if it is different (e.g. it is a new date) then it will equal the new date.

I also removed your closing and opening PHP tags to make the code easier to read.

```
$previous = '';

foreach ($record as $value) {

    $date = ($value['date'] == $previous ? '' : $value['date']);

    echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $date . '</td>
        <td>' . $value['name'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $value['email'] . '</td>
        <td>' . $value['mobile'] . '</td>
    </tr>';

    $previous = $value['date'];

}
```